# Troubleshooting Compatibility Issues When Installing Apache Airflow 2.2.3 Locally on WSL. (Ubuntu Inside Windows)

Tags: flask, installation, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, compatibility

I am installing locally apache airflow thorugh an ubuntu console inside of windows, and I followed a tutorial for the latest airflow version and it seem to be working OK. But after that, I had installed the airflow 2.2.3 version, since is the one that I need to be using for enterprise, and it doesnt seem to work. I followed every command of the tutorial and I keep getting the same error with attrs.

After running `airflow db init`, the error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 35, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 37, in <module>
    from airflow.exceptions import AirflowConfigException
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/exceptions.py", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.api_connexion.exceptions import NotFound as ApiConnextionNotFound
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/api_connexion/exceptions.py", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow._vendor.connexion import FlaskApi, ProblemException, problem
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .apis import AbstractAPI  # NOQA
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/apis/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .abstract import AbstractAPI  # NOQA
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..operations import make_operation
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/operations/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .abstract import AbstractOperation  # noqa
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/operations/abstract.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..decorators.response import ResponseValidator
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/decorators/response.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import ResponseBodyValidator
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..json_schema import Draft4RequestValidator, Draft4ResponseValidator
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/_vendor/connexion/json_schema.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openapi_spec_validator.handlers import UrlHandler
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openapi_spec_validator/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openapi_spec_validator.shortcuts import validate_spec
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openapi_spec_validator/shortcuts.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jsonschema_spec.handlers import all_urls_handler
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonschema_spec/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from jsonschema_spec.accessors import SchemaAccessor
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonschema_spec/accessors.py", line 13, in <module>
    from referencing import Registry
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/referencing/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from referencing._core import Anchor, Registry, Resource, Specification
  File "/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/referencing/_core.py", line 7, in <module>
    from attrs import evolve, field
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrs'
```

I get some errors with compatibility like the following:

```
ERROR: apache-airflow-providers-http 4.5.0 has requirement apache-airflow>=2.4.0, but you'll have apache-airflow 2.2.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-airflow-providers-ftp 3.5.0 has requirement apache-airflow>=2.4.0, but you'll have apache-airflow 2.2.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-airflow-providers-imap 3.3.0 has requirement apache-airflow>=2.4.0, but you'll have apache-airflow 2.2.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-airflow-providers-common-sql 1.6.2 has requirement apache-airflow>=2.4.0, but you'll have apache-airflow 2.2.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-airflow-providers-sqlite 3.4.3 has requirement apache-airflow>=2.4.0, but you'll have apache-airflow 2.2.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: apache-airflow-providers-http, apache-airflow-providers-ftp, apache-airflow-providers-imap, apache-airflow-providers-common-sql, apache-airflow-providers-sqlite
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/matiheilen/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/http'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have seen some videos on how to fix this and went through many stackoverflow and chatgpt answers but none of them seem to work. I think it could be a problem of installation, since the errors might be because the packages are being installed somewhere else. The other issue might be because there are versions of packages that are non compatible, but still when I try to fix it it doesnt work.

The main focus here is that I need apache airflow 2.2.3, the other versions are allowed to change. If anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix this, please help me through the comments.

1. Tried every step of this: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-attrs#install-attrs-on-macos-or-linux
2. Tried reinstalling the packages
3. Uninstalled and installed different packages that may be non compatible.